# SQL Server 2008 - update a field if date is older than 60 days

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, case

I have three fields in my user_Group table: Banner_flag, warning_Date1 & warning_Date2

What i want to do is update warning_Date2 to today's date & also set banner_flag to = '2' if the date in warning_Date1 is over 60 days old and do nothing to those that don't meet this criteria.

I'm pretty sure I need a case statment but am having trouble writing it effectively. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What does the ineffective version of your statement look like? Also, how is this related at all to .NET?

Comment: I didn't state it in my question, but I was running my SQL queries through an aspx file in .NET. Apologies it wasn't mentioned in the question itself. Wasn't sure how entirely relevant it was, but still wanted to reference it in some way so I tagged it as a keyword. I have since deleted my original statement, but now know in future to post it along with my question.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. Your suspicions are correct, it isn't directly relevant to the question you asked: the capabilities of SQL are the same no matter whether you connect from .NET, from Java, from Delphi, from sqlcmd, or from anything else. In some cases, the knowledge that you're connecting through .NET *could* prompt answers in the form of "don't do this through SQL directly, .NET has a different way of handling this" (not that that's the case here), and if you welcome answers of that kind, yeah, a note in your question works better than a tag.

Comment: Completely makes sense. Thanks for for the tip :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one single update statement can do, use `DATEDIFF`

```
UPDATE user_Group SET Banner_flag = 2, warning_Date2 = GETDATE() 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, warning_Date1, GETDATE()) >= 60 
      AND Banner_flag < 2 --This subject to your mechanism
```

Comment: Just a word of warning: `GETDATE()` may or may not match the OP's expectation of "today's date", for multiple reasons. Most importantly, `GETDATE()` includes time information as well. Less importantly, the timezone may not match your expectations. Hardly important at all: the server's clock may be out of sync.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been pulling my hair out and it was so bloody simple! Hero!

Answer (score 2):

You *could* set up a job to update the table.  Run it once per day or per hour or per minute, or whatever.

However, I think it is easier to use a view or computed column.  Start by renaming your existing `warning_date2` and `banner_flag` columns to something like `_warning_date2` and `_banner_flag` and then:

```
alter table t add warning_date2 as
    (case when dateadd(day, 60, warning_date1) <= cast(getdate() as date)
          then cast(getdate() as date) else _warning_date2
     end);

alter table t add banner_flag as
    (case when dateadd(day, 60, warning_date1) <= cast(getdate() as date)
          then '2' else _banner_flag
     end);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the below query,

```
UPDATE user_Group 
SET Banner_flag = '2', warning_Date2 = GETDATE()
WHERE warning_Date1  > DATEADD(d, -60, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Glad I could help you in anyway.